# How to apply CLT to this problem?

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

225 phones go on sale, and 100 customers are in line to buy them. If the random number of phones that each customer wishes to buy is distributed Poisson with mean 2, approximate the probability that all customers get their desired number of phones? Use Central limit theorem to solve the problem.

---

I understand that problem states to model the number of phones each customer buys as a Poisson distribution with $\lambda=2 $.

Let X be the number of phones a customer buys:

$ X \sim P_\lambda\;\;where\; \lambda  = 2\;\; E[X] = 2\;\;and\;\;V[X] = 2 $

Then we expect that each customer buys 2 phones.
And Expected total number of sales will be - by linearity of expectation:
$ E[X_1 + X_2+...X_n] = E[X_i] + E[X_2] + ...+ E[X_n] = 200 $

I don't understand how to apply all this information to compute probability that all customers get their desired number of phones. Maybe one customer wants to buy 1 phone and the other customer wants to buy 3 phones? Do we assume that all customers buy the expected number of phones? And how can I apply CLT to solve this problem?

---

**Solution:**
Let Y be $ X_1+...+X_{100} $ Then E[Y] = 200, and Var(Y) = 200
Invoke CLT, then $ Y \sim N(200,200) $
The question asks P(Y <= 225) - probability that total demand <= 225
$ P(Y<= 225)\approx \Phi (\frac{225-220}{\sqrt{200}}) \approx \Phi (1.77) = 0.9616 $

Comment: 100 customers, I will edit the question.

Comment: What is the distribution of the total number of phones the $100$ customers want to buy? (Presumably each customer is independent of the others)

Comment: The problem doesn't give the distribution. And I don't know.

Comment: It is worth remembering that the sum of independent Poisson distributed random variables has a Poisson distribution with parameter equal to the sum of the individual parameters.

Comment: Though if you are going to use a Central Limit Theorem approximation you could sidestep that.  You have stated the mean and variance for each customer's demand and the mean of the total demand.   What is the variance of the total demand?

Comment: Customer demand=> mean and variance is 2, and total demand mean 200, and variance 200. Because V(X+Y) = V(X) + V(Y). But then what is where I'm stuck at. I understand CLT says the total demand is distributed as N(200,200)

Comment: Why would a customer stand in line to buy 0 phones?

Comment: OK - So what is the probability that a  random variabale approximately distributed as $N(200,200)$ exceeds $225$ (or is $226$ or more - you might use $225.5$ as a cuttoff to deal with this continuity issue)

Comment: You want $P[X_1 + ... + X_{100} > 225]$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why we want to find out probability that N(200,200) exceeds 225.

Comment: Oh shoot, I misinterpreted the problem, now I see what the problem is asking. Thank you for the help!

Comment: In R: `ppois(225, 200)` returns exact answer $0.9623$ and
`pnorm((224.5-200)/sqrt(200))`
$0.9584,$ which is accurate to two places--about as good as you can expect with normal approximation to binomial.
 returns normal approximation
$0.9615,$ which is accurate to two places--about what you can expect

Comment: @BruceET `pnorm((225.5-200)/sqrt(200))` is even better, at `0.9643`